# What kind of window is this (and how do I fix it)?

Tags: windows

I have a single hung (vinyl?) window in one room that is different from all the rest of the windows.  The balance mechanism just failed and I'd like to repair it.  Can someone tell me a name for this window (or even better, a guide for repairing one)?

Instead of a spiral balance or a counterweight, it appears to have a mechanism that is entirely contained within the stile of the window and moves up and down with it (I'd never noticed it before).  One of the sides has failed and the window now sags down on that side when raised.  The balance mechanism has dropped down from the window itself so it can be seen.  It has a metal track and a cord (that I assume is broken).

[image: Window with balance mechanism below]

If possible, I'd like to find a guide on how to attack this thing.  I'm not sure how to properly remove/replace it.  Right now, I can still close the window.  I'd rather not just fiddle and make that part not work.

My internet searching hasn't worked well, so I suspect there's a term for this window that I don't know.  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: A picture of the non-broken side might have helped. Glad you got it fixed, though.

Answer (score 8):

I had never seen these before, but I was finally able to track down some information and replace the broken mechanism.  My windows bear a "Viking" name, but I didn't find anyone selling parts under that name.

However, the useful term for these are "channel balance" or "block and tackle balance" windows.  With that term, it's possible to find replacement parts and even some youtube videos showing the process of replacement.